# Size in bytes of a 4-bit row of pixels?

Tags: c#, graphics, bitmap, stride

Take the following example, for a row of pixels that is **2 pixels wide**:

- 4-bit: 1 byte long row (2 pixels = 1 byte) **(currently, I get 2 instead of 1)**
- 8-bit: 2 bytes long row, (1 pixel = 1 byte)
- 16-bit: 4 bytes long row (1 pixel = 2 bytes)
- 24-bit: 6 bytes long row (1 pixel = 3 bytes)
- 32-bit: 8 bytes long row (1 pixel = 4 bytes)

Something's definitely wrong in the formula but I can't figure it out:

```
const int rowWidthPixels = 2;

foreach (var bitsPerPixel in new[] { 4, 8, 16, 24, 32 })
{
    var bytesPerPixel = (bitsPerPixel + 7) / 8;

    var message1 = $"{nameof(bytesPerPixel)}: {bytesPerPixel}";

    switch (bitsPerPixel)
    {
        case 4:
            Assert.AreEqual(1, bytesPerPixel, message1);
            break;
        case 8:
            Assert.AreEqual(1, bytesPerPixel, message1);
            break;
        case 16:
            Assert.AreEqual(2, bytesPerPixel, message1);
            break;
        case 24:
            Assert.AreEqual(3, bytesPerPixel, message1);
            break;
        case 32:
            Assert.AreEqual(4, bytesPerPixel, message1);
            break;
    }

    var bytesPerRow = rowWidthPixels * bytesPerPixel;

    var message2 = $"{nameof(bytesPerRow)}: {bytesPerRow}";

    switch (bitsPerPixel)
    {
        case 4:
            Assert.AreEqual(1, bytesPerRow, message2); // BUG this should be 1 but currently is 2
            break;
        case 8:
            Assert.AreEqual(2, bytesPerRow, message2);
            break;
        case 16:
            Assert.AreEqual(4, bytesPerRow, message2);
            break;
        case 24:
            Assert.AreEqual(6, bytesPerRow, message2);
            break;
        case 32:
            Assert.AreEqual(8, bytesPerRow, message2);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `var bytesPerRow = (bitsPerPixel * pixelsPerRow + 7) / bitsPerByte;` :o)

Comment: @SirRufo Thank you for figuring that one out! 

Comment: @SirRufo the `+7` should be `+bitsPerByte-1` in case `bitsPerByte` is not `8` ...

Comment: @Spektre yes, of course :o)

Comment: Proper generic formula in fact is `(bits * width + 7) / 8`  as it works for 1-bit per pixel too. 